# Why the mediated effect is the result of the multiplication between the slope of IV to mediator and the slope of mediator to DV?

Tags: mediation

My question is, why the average causal mediated effect (ACME) can be calculated as the two coefficients that represent the slope from the independent variable to the mediator (simple regression model) and between the mediator and the dependent variable (the full regression model)?
I know that if we replace in the full model the M with the simple regression M ~ X we can easily obtain that multiplication, but what underlies that reasoning?